# Styling issue with react-share button and text

Tags: reactjs, react-share

When I am trying to add text in front of FacebookIcon by using react-share, the text is not aligned to the icon. I have gone through the docs but couldn`t find anything useful.

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/rrlli?file=/src/App.js

Library home: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share

I have tried to add text in span tag and trying adding style but it didn`t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the text is not aligned to the icon

Then just apply a new *className* for the wrapper and set `align-items` to `center`.

```
.align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-share-facebook-and-twitter-example-forked-hcfhfk